# How to disable <a> button in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-blade

I have a button in `<a>` tag like below.

```
<a type="button" href="{{ url('/team') }}" class="btn btn-primary team">Team</a>
```

I want to disable this button in some conditions so i used jquery to disable. I implement something like below.

```
$('.team').prop("disabled", true);
```

But it didn't disabled.
Instead of `<a>` if i use `<button>` it works.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, bootstrap also has a disabled class, which will put cursor to default arrow and styles like disabled item.

```
$('.team').addClass("disabled");
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wvbcxj50/1/

Comment: Yes i removed `.prop("disabled", true)` from above answer. Now also it's working. So answer will be come like `$('.team').addClass("disabled");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you don't want the user to redirect on click

```html
<a href="javascript: void(0)">I am a useless link</a>
```

Comment: $('.team').prop("href", 'javascript: void(0)');

Comment: I don't think it's a proper way.

Comment: Because cursor is also available as clickable.

Answer (score 0):

as one of the options you can put a button in a block

```
<div id="btdis"><a type="button" href="{{ url('/team') }}" class="btn btn-primary team">Team</a></div>
```

if need disable

```
document.getElementById('btdis').innerHTML='';
```

if need enable

```
document.getElementById('btdis').innerHTML='<a type="button" href="{{ url('/team') }}" class="btn btn-primary team">Team</a>'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But actually i expect a proper way to disable. Like as mention in question `$('.team').prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: maybe it will work, I don’t have the opportunity to check now <a id="team" type="button" href="{{ url('/team') }}" class="btn btn-primary team">Team</a>  $('#team').prop("disabled", true);